# T-SQL query to filter a group of rows with specific column data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have tables A and B as below

Table A

```
Column1 Column2
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
```

Table B

```
Column3 Column4 Column5
1   AB  10
1   OP  2
2   OP  2
3   AB  10
```

I want to get the resulting output after join as

```
TableA.Column2  Column6
A   10
B   NULL
C   10
```

I am joining tables A and B on A.column1 = B.Column3

For each A.column1 I want to get only the B.Column5 in TableC.Column6 where B.Column4=’AB’

For the A.Column1 rows where B.Column4 not equals ’AB’ C.Column6 should be NULL

I have tried the following options but it is not giving the desired output:

1. Applied the condition in join clause with ‘and’ and where – It gave me only records with B.Column4=’AB’

   ```
    TableA.Column2  Column6
        A             10
        C             10
   ```
2. Join without any where clause and applied ‘case when  then B.Column5 else NULL end’ in select

   ```
    select 
        A.Column2, 
        case 
            when B.Column4 = ’AB’ 
                then B.Column5 
                else NULL 
        end as Column6
    from 
        A
    join 
        B on (A.Column1 = B.Column3)
   ```

Here I am getting all the values as below, 2nd row is not expected:

```
TableA.Column2  Column6
A   10
A   NULL
B   NULL
C   10
```

Please suggest here

Answer (score 0):

You're close.  Just grab the maximum of the CASE result

```
SELECT 
       A.Column2
       , MAX(CASE WHEN B.Column4 = 'AB' THEN B.Column5 ELSE NULL END) AS Column6
FROM  A INNER JOIN B ON A.Column1 = B.Column3
GROUP BY A.Column2
```